# How to Show a div near Cursor position on hover in React js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hover, onhover

I have two Text Items, item1 and item2, and a div with some text inside. I want to keep the div hidden by default but show it at cursor position when I hover on Text item1 or item2.
[Please check the sample GIF animation in this Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4lpB.gif)

I tried this in Jquery code inside React. But it gives error.

```
$(".text-item").mouseenter(function (e) {
  $(".box")
    .css({
      position: "absolute",
      right: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY,
      display: "block",
    })
    .show();
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow :) Could you share what you tried so far ?

Comment: $(".text-item").mouseenter(function (e) {
  $(".box")
    .css({
      position: "absolute",
      right: e.pageX,
      top: e.pageY,
      display: "block",
    })
    .show();
});

I tried to do it in jquery code inside React. But not working. How to write this code in React Language.

Comment: I edited my question and added the required piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import {useState, Fragment} from react;

const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

const MyApp = ()=> {
  return ( 
      <Fragment> {
         visible && 
         <div className="hiddenContainer>
            <p>Your hidden text</p>
         </div>
      }
      </Fragment>
      <p onMouseEnter={()=>setVisible(!visible)}>Item 1</p>
      <p onMouseEnter={()=>setVisible(!visible)}>Item 2</p>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Its working. But the code to show hiddenContainer near cursor is not present in this.

Comment: Did you tried hovering over item 1 or itmem2?

Comment: Yes I tried hovering on both.

Comment: I just edited the code and it should work just fine now.